# Scrolling is not working properly in some version of android

Tags: android

Scrolling is working smoothly on Android L but when I am running it in Android J the scrolling is not working properly, it scrolls very slowly when I try to scroll in some particular part of screen. It is not the problem of the phone because I have tested it on couple of Android J phones. I am not sure what am I missing here.

```
<LinearLayout
...

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:isScrollContainer="true">


        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your are using RecyclerView inside a ScrollView. A RecyclerView *is* a ScrollView (it implements that class). Because of this you have two scrollviews fighting for touch events and when that happens your app becomes unpredictable, which is bad. I don't honestly know why it works on lollipop.